# Python (Pygame) return angle in specific interval

Tags: python, rotation, pygame, intervals, angle

I have this code:

```
def getAngle(x1, y1, x2, y2):
rise = y1 - y2
run = x1 - x2
angle = math.atan2(run, rise) # get the angle in radians
angle = angle * (180 / math.pi) # convert to degrees
angle = (angle) % 360 # adjust for a right-facing sprite
return angle
```

... which is returning an angle depending on mouse position on the screen.

I want to set an interval where rotation of my object will stop at the specific point. For an example: if angle is bigger than 90° i want my object to stop getting higher angle. In this case 90° should be like some border where rotation stops.

I think i need 2 conditions becouse angle shouldn't be higher from 90° on the left and right.

Anyone got an idea how to solve that?

this part of the code is in the game loop (it uses defined getAngle):

```
    mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for cannonx, cannony in (((width/2)-45, height-25), ((width/2)-45, height-25)):
        degrees = getAngle(cannonx, cannony, mousex, mousey)
        rotcannonImg = pygame.transform.rotate(cannonImg, degrees)
        rotcannonRect = rotcannonImg.get_rect()
        rotcannonRect.center = (cannonx, cannony)
        windowSurface.blit(rotcannonImg, rotcannonRect)
```

Comment: You can use `math.degrees()` to convert radians to degrees

Answer (score 0):

The phrase “angle shouldn't be higher from 90° on the left and right” does not have a well-defined meaning in English, so I am not sure what you intend.  However, the following figure shows the relations between various angles and the signs of rise and run when point (x1, y1) is located where the lines cross and (x2, y2) is in particular octants.  Note, dy = rise, dx = run.  That is, you might be able to test signs of rise and run to get the information you want.
[image: lines and octant relations]

Comment: thank you for this answer. however, i set while loop, to get an angle like this:
while math.fabs(run) > 0 and rise > math.fabs(run):
        return angle

but now, everytime when angle is greater than that, my program quits and stops. what am i doing wrong'

Comment: I think he wants to clamp the values to -90deg to 90deg.

Comment: Made it! Solution:

    if math.fabs(run) > 0 and rise > math.fabs(run):
        return angle
    elif run < 0:
        angle = 315
        return angle
    elif run > 0:
        angle = 45
        return angle

So everytime my "cannon" reaches max of 0 < -dx < dy and 0 < dx < dy , it stops at this angle.

**Thank you, jwpat7!** :)